# survdiff one-sample test - how can I use the offset term in a formula?

Tags: r

I would like to use the survdiff function for a one-sample test.

I did not understand where should I include in the furmula the offset term.

The `surdiff` should look like this:

```
survdiff(formula, data, subset, na.action, rho=0)
```

For ex., in k-samples test, the formula would be: `Surv(futime, fustat)` and the predictors is: `rx`. And we would use the surdiff in the following way:

```
survdiff(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx,data=ovarian)
```

(This ex. is taken from the R example)

What I do not understand is, how I should include the offset term in the predictors in a case I want to perform a one-sample test. In the R explanation they say I should use the offset(sp) where sp is the probabilities vector.

Does anyone can tell me what is the correct syntax for this, and do they mean by 'include'?

Thanks in advance!!
Alley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include `offset(var)` as the *only* thing on the RHS of the model formula, and `var` must be a *survival probability*, the latter can be computed using the `survexp` function.

If you'd read a bit further on in `?survdiff`, down to the examples, you'd have seen this:

```
## Expected survival for heart transplant patients based on
## US mortality tables
expect <- survexp(futime ~ ratetable(age=(accept.dt - birth.dt),
                  sex = 1, year = accept.dt, race = "white"), jasa,
                  cohort = FALSE, ratetable = survexp.usr)

## actual survival is much worse (no surprise)
survdiff(Surv(jasa$futime, jasa$fustat) ~ offset(expect))
```

which shows you **exactly** how to include a single `offset` term in a `survdiff` formula.

Comment: Great thanks, I missed that ex. as I expected to see one-sample test ex.

Regarding the sruvexp, I have tried to use it and I did not understand why it demands to get 'age' value.. this parameter belongs to the rmap - which is an optional parameter. Furthermore, in my experiments, I do not use this 'age' at all.. 

If you could advice me how to use the survexp vector without having 'age' parameter, it would be very nice. Thanks again for your help! Alley

Comment: Nice reply, Gavin. Here's a good citation for the one-sample method (in addition to all the resources that Therneau has posted at his Mayo website on group expected survival estimates.)    http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/95/19/1434.full